# How do I get my custom gradle tasks to run?

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project from which I want to generate two artifacts - a java jar, and a tarball of additional files.

So I added the following to my build.gradle

```
def serviceName = "kafka-schemas"

task packageDistribution(type: Copy) {
    from "$buildDir/resources/main"
    include "*.avsc"
    into "$buildDir/schemas"
}

task archive(type: Tar) {
    dependsOn 'packageDistribution'
    compression = 'GZIP'
    from("$buildDir/schemas") {
        include "**/*.avsc"
    }
    into("${serviceName}")
}

project.tasks.findByName('build') dependsOn archive
project.tasks.findByName('build') dependsOn packageDistribution
```

However when I run `gradle clean build` it does not run my tasks.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: packageDistribution should depend on processResources, since it copies what processResources generates. Note that you do not need two tasks. You could generate a tarball drectly from $buildDir/resources/main

Comment: I think you just missed the dot before ".dependsOn". I think you can also write "build.dependsOn(archive)". gradle resolves such undeclared variables at runtime by looking up tasks.

Comment: I got it. The tasks were running, it is just that they ran at the very beginning. I wanted them to run just before the end of the build. So I added a finalizedBy to make them run just before the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
processResources.dependsOn('packageDistribution')
task packageDistribution(type: Zip) {
archiveFileName = "xxxxx.zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/dist")

    from "xxxx"
}
```